# How to gracefully restart an unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, unicorn

I have a servers which deploying with chef each 1 minute.
For restart unicorn i send the USR2 signal to old master, then try to decrement old workers by code:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|

  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  # This allows a new master process to incrementally
  # phase out the old master process with SIGTTOU to avoid a
  # thundering herd when doing a transparent upgrade. The last worker
  # spawned will then kill off the old master process with a SIGQUIT.
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end

  # sleep 1
end
```

And, finally, send the QUIT signal to old master

And each time i receive following message in logs:

```
E, [2013-07-03T10:56:19.983813 #19955] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (1 tries left)
E, [2013-07-03T10:56:20.484468 #19955] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
E, [2013-07-03T10:56:20.484595 #19955] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (0 tries left)
E, [2013-07-03T10:56:20.985190 #19955] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)                   
/my_path/766ea02ce174c37de606c1960c498d53c5fb602b/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.4.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `initialize': Address  already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Which means that new master cannot be started (i didn't see new master in process list) but old master cannot be shut down and quantity of workers is constant.

What i may do in wrong way?
Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 2 steps to resolve the issue:

1) Removed application_root from unicorn.conf.rb
2) Set maximum quantity of workers from 32 to 16

Then error was disappeared from logs.

Answer (score 1):

Graceful way to restart unicorn will be a rake task in Rakefile:

```
task :restart_server => :environment do
     system("kill -QUIT `cat pids/unicorn.pid`")
     system("bundle exec unicorn_rails -c ./config/unicorn.rb -D")
end
```

It is assumed here that the path of file "unicorn.pid", the  main server process is present in application_root/pids/unicorn.pid. This path can be changed by changing the value of pid in config/unicorn.rb

```
pid "pids/unicorn.pid"
```

Also, if you are using cap for deployment, make sure this file had write permission on remote servers and add this file to .gitignore so that this file does not override your local pid value onto remote production and test servers.